# Distribution List with Groups

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

I am running Exchange 2010. Within AD I have the following:

- BranchManager <- this is an OU

  - Branch1 <- this is a universal security group containing a name
  - Branch2 <- this is a universal security group containing a name
  - AllBranch <- this is a universal security group containing Branch1 & Branch2

In Exchange I want to create a distribution group for AllBranch that sends emails to Branch1 and Branch2

Has anyone done something like this before? So far I've been unable to get this to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you mail-enabled the security groups yet via Exchange PowerShell?

Enable-DistributionGroup -Identity “groupname”

Security groups are not mail enabled by default.

Comment: Skyler I did mail enable all Branch and AllBranch groups, still doesn't work

Comment: What do you have set for the group restrictions set here: Properties>Mail Flow Settings>Message Delivery Restrictions.

Comment: Interesting, it seemed to take a few minutes to propagate but now I have a mail group called AllBranch and it contains the groups Branch1 and Branch2. In other words it works the way I want it to. Thank you for your help.